# Source in the Aruch HaShulchan to not motzi (exempt) others with after-bracha on mezonot foods

Tags: halacha, blessing, motzi-yedei-chovato, mezonot-beracha, aruch-hashulchan

The Aruch HaShulchan has an opinion on whether one person can motzi (exempt) a crowd with a bracha acharona (after-bracha) on mezonot foods.  It is along the lines of it is better not to have one person do this for everyone else.  I saw it once, and now cannot find it.  I have since heard it is "famous"!  Does any one have a source?

Comment: Just FTR I don't think it's only the Aruch HaShulchan who holds this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[AhS OH 213:6](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%92#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A8.D7.99.D7.92_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.95)

> And thus is the halachah and the widespread custom that one does not discharge another's obligation in any [brachah], and each makes his own brachah, since even for "Hamotzi" and birkas ha-mazon, there are few in our time [who follow the practice of] one being motzi another, and all the more so for other things.

He goes on to cover be-di-avad cases.

Comment: thanks.  it was 213:4 specifically on mezonot and after bracha because of lack of kvius, but thanks so much.  also nice translation - was it your own?