# Can the threefold blessing be said motzi others who ate different foods?

Tags: blessing, motzi-yedei-chovato, birkat-meeyn-shalosh

Can the threefold blessing be said in one combined form motzi others who ate different foods requiring different versions of the bracha?

For example: I'm saying bracha acharona after eating cake and grapes and also wanting to be motzi for two others, one had cake and the other had grapes. Can I say the combined version of the bracha for hamichya and haeitz with everyone in mind?

If not, what should I do in this situation?

I'm thinking specifically of situations when an a parent is saying the bracha acharona for children but perhaps the same principle applies more widely.

Comment: can you explain a reason to think that it is not good to motsi others?

Comment: It's not a very good reason, but: each person saying ameyn is saying it to a bracha that applies only partly to them.

Comment: @kouty There is no Zimmun except for bread. Why would this work?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26217/759

Answer (score 1):

This is an attempt to answer following my lecture of the question. Following Rabenu Tam and RI (1), Shomea Keone is a an expression which has almost a literal sense. If you use "the shomea keone din"  when you are in middle of a passage  in which you cannot interrupt, the result of shomea keone is that you made an interruption despite your silence.

So, the question is the equivalent of this: If someone needs to make al haets veal peri haets and he said (by mistake) al hamichia veal haets, is it good, or is there interruptions in middle of the bracha al haets?

Partial answer. If the is careful to use the din shomea keone for the needed passages only, there is no interruptions an its a good bracha acharona. But if he did use the din shomea keone for the whole bracha he listened, the question is as described in the first paragraph. And I can answer according to the bet yosef in hilchot purim who said that saying al hanissim when not needed is not an interruption. So it's good there is no problem.

---

(1) Tosfot Berachot 2b

> ור''ת ור''י היו אומרים דאדרבה אי שומע כעונה הוי הפסקה אם שותק

Comment: I sense you've got the answer, but the way you've written is not very clear. Is this what you're saying: that if the person listening is very careful only to be yotzei during the parts of the bracha that apply to what he ate, then it's ok? What about the person speaking??

Comment: ...Are you saying that the person speaking also has to be careful only to be motzei the other person for the parts that apply to that person? And then it's fine for both? (That is, there would be more of a problem for the person who is yotezi than for the person who is motzei, insofar as an interruption in the blessing is concerned?)